# Ember findRecord and include

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I have a component which needs to query a service for homes in a postcode. This is to populate a select dropdown list in response to a user entering a postcode.

So I have

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    actions: {
        findHome: function(){
            // component declared for promise
            var component = this;
            var postcode = this.get( 'area.postcode');
            var store = this.get('store');

            // EITHER...
            var x = store.findRecord('postcode', postcode, {include: 'homes'})
                .then( function (area) {
                    component.set( 'homes', area.homes);
            });

            // OR...  
            var x = store.findRecord('postcode', postcode, {include: 'homes'})
            component.set( 'homes', x.homes );

        }
    }
});
```

Anyway,it doesn't work as neither solution has a proper array of `homes`. How should I be doing this?

I can see Mirage returning the data (postcode and included homes) in response to the findRecord.

Comment: Long-shot... but did you name a service 'store' in addition to the default store that is already defined?

Comment: I can't see any default store already defined, hence the one named in the above component.

Comment: There are a few 'magic' things about Ember that are injected explicitly, just like there are explicit index routes. You can call this.store - or this.get('store') just about everywhere. I would try renaming your service and see if things behave differently. Like a said, it's a long shot... and the store may only be there if you use ember-data or something... but you should look into that. : )

Comment: store is not magically injected into components; it is into routes and controllers.

Comment: Cool. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't getting defined twice. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ember-data, [relationship return Promises](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises). so in your case you might alter your first option little bit like the below,

```
store.findRecord('postcode', postcode, {include: 'homes'})
    .then( function (area) {                
        area.get('homes').then((result)=>{  component.set( 'homes',result);
        });
    });
```

Remember your second option is wrong, since [findRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord) return Prmise, so you are setting Prmoise instead of result to `homes`.

Comment: If it doesn't answer your question, then you might need to include your model code and also the way you confirmed mirage response ?.

Comment: Thanks very much, I thought the second choice was wrong, but I couldn't understand why the first one wasn't returning the Objects I needed.

Comment: I haven't used ember-data much. Just read guides to answer this question. In this [guide link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises) explained, While working with relationships it is important to remember that they return promises.

Comment: I got the promises bit, it was my understanding of how to use them that was wrong :/